# How to safely solve a pair of elementary equations in a floating point computing system?

Tags: numerical-methods

I wrote a simple short computer program to solve a pair of equations of the format ,

- $y = a1 * x + b1$
- $y = a2 * x + b2$ .

But , it outputs clearly wrong answers sometimes when $abs(a1)$ or $abs(a2)$ is very small ,but not zero.
I analyze the problem as follows.
When it computes $a1-a2$ for very small $a2$, the floating point function computes as $a1-a2 = a1$ . Is it possible and how do mathematicians safely solve these equations in their researches?

Thank you in advance.

For details, my algorithm follows.

- check $ a1 != a2 $ ;
- $0 = (a1-a2)x+(b1-b2)$;
- $x=-1*(b1-b2)/(a1-a2)$.

Comment: If by "very small $a_2$" you mean $a_2$ is close to $0$, then it sounds like your language doesn't carry enough digits of precision and is rounding $a_2$ down to $0$. What language/software are you using?

Comment: @AustinMohr,the language is flash action script3, I admit it is not for  solving mathematics.

Comment: You may already be using it, but there is a Number data type that seems to allow for a fair amount of precision. You can read about it [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ActionScript#Data_types).

Comment: @AustinMohr,yes I did. But I thought that Number type holds only single float numbers,instead of double float ones.Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you equate the $y$'s, you get $a2*x+b2=a1*x+b1$ or $x=\frac{b1-b2}{a2-a1}$.  Subtraction of nearly equal quantities can lose precision.  It isn't so much $a1$ or $a2$ being small compared to $1$, it is $a2-a1$ being small compared to $a1$.  Think of subtracting $1.000001-.999999$ when  both have only $6$ digits precision.  If each one is $\pm 1 e-6$, the difference is $\pm 2 e-6$ which is a disaster if the difference is $2 e-6$.  Sometimes there is no help.  If these two lines have almost the same slope, the intersection is badly defined.  But if you have a quadratic, there is help.  Section 5.6 of [Numerical Recipes](http://apps.nrbook.com/c/index.html) and many numerical analysis texts discuss how to solve that here.