# Is Matlab free from cancellation of digits in solving elementary equations?

Tags: matlab

Few days ago,I had a problem solving elementary equations in flash action script 3.
I asked here and got an anwer ,I thank him very much.

1. [How to safely solve a pair of elementary equations in a floating point computing system?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/98959/how-to-safely-solve-a-pair-of-elementary-equations-in-a-floating-point-computing)

I temporary fixed the program to replace any equation representing a straight line almost parallel to y axis by a new line completely parallel to y axis. Currently it seems that the fixed program finds the meeting point of 2 straight lines correctly if they are not parallel to each other.

Then , let me ask you my new question.
If I use Matlab to solve the same problems , do I also need to do similar checking relating "cancellation of digits"?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know Mathematica, and believe Matlab, distinguishes between exact values (like integers, fractions, $\pi$, etc.) and approximate values (1.1023).  Calculations with exact values are exact (when possible) and will not suffer from cancellation.  It will be able to do $\frac1{10^9}-\frac1{10^9+1}=\frac1{10^{18}+10^9}$ accurately, with no loss of precision.  If you ask for $0.000000001-0.00000000999999999000000000999999999$ you will lose precision because they are approximate numbers.

Comment: Mathematica does this, Matlab does not. Matlab stores numbers as ordinary floating point values, and will suffer from the same problems Actionscript does.

Comment: http://www.cs.utah.edu/~germain/PPS/Topics/Matlab/symbolic_math.html